# How to select an element across inner <HTML> tag contained in a Iframe with jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, selector

I have a weird page with a HTML tag inside another HTML tag, (I know... but it's beyond my control), I try to select the element inside the inner one with jQuery but no luck. Seems like jQuery won't go across second HTML tag?

For example

```
<HTML>
    <Body>
        <div id="foo"> 
            <iframe>
                <HTML>
                    <Body>
                        <div>
                        ^^^^ select this div ^^^^
                        </div>
                    </Body>
                </HTML>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </Body>
</HTML>
```

I could not select the div (with bar in it) with

```
 $('#foo>iframe>HTML>Body>div')
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Sry, in the actual code there is no Id for that div, it was a bad example, I just changed it.

Comment: Fix your HTML markup to be legal so that normal DOM queries will work.  There is only one `<html>` and `<body>` tag per frame/iframe.

Comment: Since the HTML is invalid, it depends on what the browser has done to try to recover from the error.

Comment: Sry guys, did not know that iframe plays a big part in this. I have modified the code to show the correct structure.

Comment: Is the code inside the iframe actually between the iframe tags (i.e. is the alternative content for when iframes are not supported or disabled) or is it the document that is loaded into the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the question was updated, so my previous answer was invalid.

First - Sort out your HTML markup, it is invalid. This is the correct structure for the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="foo">
        <div>
        <p> bar </p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The jquery to select the div with "bar" inside it is:

```
$('#foo > div > p ').html();  // Returns "bar"
```

Check this [JSFiddle for more info & example: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnysu/) :  http://jsfiddle.net/nnysu/

Comment: Thanks, just want to select div, not p.  p is there just to indicate that is the div I want to select. Sorry for not being very clear

Answer (score 0):

I would just use this selector:

```
$('#foo div p');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NCEk8/)

Comment: Hi thanks, but do you know how to select the div it self that contains bar? Since I want to modify it, thanks!

Comment: You can use :contains(text) selector to double check, `$('#foo div p:contains(bar)')`

Comment: Hi Sorry, I think I explained my question wrong, what I want to do is just select the div itself as an object. so I can do $('this_div').css("width","30px");  the "bar" inside is just to point out that the specific div I want to select. Sorry for the confusion. I also modified the question more to make my question more clear. sry sry.

Comment: Your example doesn't have an iframe.